# C++17: map type to integer value at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I have the following types:

```cpp
struct A { }; 
struct B { }; 
struct C { }; 

template <typename Class, uint16_t i>     
struct def {                              
        using message_type = Class;       
        static constexpr uint16_t tag = i;
};
```

and this tuple:

```cpp
constexpr auto types = std::make_tuple(def<A, 1>(), def<B, 2>(), def<C, 3>());
```

Types A, B and C should be mapped to corresponding values (A -> 1 etc.). I want to create something (function, struct) that given object of one of these types will return proper value. I tried doing the following:

```cpp
template <typename T>                                                                    
struct gettag {                                                                          
        static decltype(T::tag) value(typename T::message_type const&) { return T::tag; }
};                                                                                       

template <typename... Args>                                                              
struct tagdb : public gettag<Args>... {                                                  
        tagdb(std::tuple<Args...> const& t) { }                                          
};                                                                                       
int main() {                            
        tagdb t(types);                 
        A a;                            
        std::cout << t.value(a) << '\n';
}
```

This does not work, `g++` claims that request for member `value` is ambiguous:

```
x.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
x.cc:29:17: error: request for member ‘value’ is ambiguous
   29 |  std::cout << t.value(a) << '\n';
      |                 ^~~~~
x.cc:16:26: note: candidates are: ‘static decltype (T::tag) gettag<T>::value(const typename T::message_type&) [with T = def<C, 3>; decltype (T::tag) = const short unsigned int; typename T::message_type = C]’
   16 |  static decltype(T::tag) value(typename T::message_type const&) { return T::tag; }
      |                          ^~~~~
x.cc:16:26: note:                 ‘static decltype (T::tag) gettag<T>::value(const typename T::message_type&) [with T = def<B, 2>; decltype (T::tag) = const short unsigned int; typename T::message_type = B]’
x.cc:16:26: note:                 ‘static decltype (T::tag) gettag<T>::value(const typename T::message_type&) [with T = def<A, 1>; decltype (T::tag) = const short unsigned int; typename T::message_type = A]’
```

I am a little surprised, especially since it clearly shows that each method is parameterized using different types.

Is there a way to make this solution work or should I completely change my approach? Note that what I want to avoid most is writing overloads for each type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have template base classes, all of which declare a member with the same name. The easiest fix is just to pull all the base class `value` functions into the derived class:

`using gettag<Args>::value...;`

See https://godbolt.org/z/F_Prhg

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm indeed. Although template base classes declare same name, they do so with different argument types. So which rule says that they can't be used without "using"? I suppose it is something basic.

Comment: It's name lookup: members template base classes of a class template that depend on the template args of the outer class template are not considered for lookup of non-dependent names. The `using` makes them members of the `tagdb` class, so they are considered during name lookup.

Comment: Ok, this is not *that* basic, thanks. No wonder I didn't knew what happened. This seems overly complicated, although I supposed that not doing it would makes things work in quite mysterious ways sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a solution without a `std::tuple` and `gettag`:

```
struct A { }; 
struct B { }; 
struct C { }; 

template <typename Class, std::uint16_t i>     
struct def {                              
    static constexpr std::uint16_t value(Class) {
        return i;
    }
};  

template <typename... Tags>                                                              
struct tagdb : public Tags... {                                                  
    using Tags::value...;
};

template<class... Tags>
constexpr auto make_tagdb(Tags...) {
    return tagdb<Tags...>{};
}

// template<class... Tags>
// constexpr auto make_tagdb(std::tuple<Tags...>) {
//     return tagdb<Tags...>{};
// }

constexpr auto tags = make_tagdb(def<A, 1>(), def<B, 2>(), def<C, 3>());

int main() {                            
    A a;                            
    std::cout << tags.value(a) << '\n';   // Output: 1
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks, unfortunately this tuple is a must, it is generated by protobuf compiler plugin and I can't change it. Apart from that your solution is very nice, I'll see if in the future it could be used in our solution. Thank you.

Comment: @JędrzejDudkiewicz You can use the commented overload to construct `tagdb` from `std::tuple`. Actually, after I typed my answer, I realized that I essentially repeated Anthony's answer with a small simplification by removing `gettag` class that looks redundant anyway.